# Passing URL params from the database

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7

I am trying to build a full stack web application. In my database, I have a table with lots of data that looks something like:

```
SHOWS
ID          show_name              show_number
1              First Show                  2
2              Second Show                 1
3             Third Show                   1
4              fourth Show                 2
5              Fifth Show                  3
6             Sixth Show                   1
```

If you can see, I have show number as a column on the side. This show number could be any number from 1-32. What I am trying to do is to have a URL that will have those show_number as a type of parameter by setting up url pattern.

In my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^show/(?P<show_number>\d+)$', views.slideshow),
]
```

And when I go to …/show/1/,
All rows with show_number 1 will be on that page. If I go to …../show/2/ all rows with show_number 2 will go there and so on.

In my models.py:

```
def show_screen(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT show_number, show_name FROM shows ORDER BY show_number ASC;")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return data
```

In my views:

```
def slideshow(request):
    context = {
        "shows": Show.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Towards the end of this project, my goal is to let my url dynamically change every some seconds. Is there a way to pass a url pattern directly from the database?

Let's say every 30 seconds, my page should go to

```
www./....../show/1/
www./....../show/2/
www./....../show/3/
www./....../show/7/
www./....../show/19/
```

After it reaches the last URL param, it goes back to first URL.

Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: What is the purpose of passing the url from the database? You do not have any urls stored in your db.

Comment: What determines the next `show_number` in your url list? or is this list set by you?

Comment: Im passing the show_number as part of the url pattern of my url. I do not have url string on my database. I only have the show_number which I want to become part of my url. These show_number is selected by client. they can chose a number from 1-32.

Comment: I understand that. My question was referencing your question towards the end of your post: `Is there a way to pass a url pattern directly from the database?` I am not sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1):

Your view needs to accept the `show_number` variable that you have defined in your `urls.py`:

```
def slideshow(request, show_number):
```

Then you need to filter the show objects based on the value of `show_number`:

```
Show.objects.filter(show_number=show_number)
```

Full view code:

```
def slideshow(request, show_number):
    context = {
        "shows": Show.objects.filter(show_number=show_number)
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

For the second part of your question, I would do the following:

- Determine the next url server-side in the `slideshow` view
- Return this url as part of the response
- Use javascript on the client-side to load this new url when the time comes to transition to the next slideshow

  - e.g. `window.location.href = '://your_url';`

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to pass in my show_number param as I was typing my question. I will work around with this problem and see if I come up with anything. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Marvin If my answer helped you solve your problem, you can upvote and accept it. If you are still having problems with this, I am happy to continue to help.